# Use of selector to delete data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete some selected files but it is not working on my webserver on the net, but it is working very well on the local server. No error was display on the webserver. Can someone help?

```
<?php
    global $db;
    include('dbcon.php');
    if (isset($_POST['delete_report'])) {
        $id=$_POST['selector'];
        $N = count($id);
        for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
            $db->query("DELETE FROM report where report_id='$id[$i]'");
        }
        header("location: reports.php");exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have error .. ?

Comment: print `$db->error;` after the query and give the result back please.

Comment: Where do you establish your database connection? Also Massively insecure code and sql injection ready.

Comment: I observed that the data was  deleted but it still shows on the table as if it is not deleted until i log out. what might be the cause

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You also need to read up on the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct. This is a really inefficient way to do iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page after delete solves the problem. the system refuses to load header("location: reports.php");exit; but just show a plain white screen while in locahost server it loads the header("location:reports.php)

my dbcon.php is

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'retreat';

//Connect and select the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```